# During Magento Installation which files get changed

Tags: php, database, magento, installation

During a Magento (CE) installation, which files are changed by the installer.

Is it just local.xml?

Basically, i would like to know as I would like to have a fresh codebase to use with an existing database

Comment: Just do a diff. Although, I'm not sure why you need a 'fresh codebase' - I think you are just looking to edit the database configuration. And you do that here: /app/etc/local.xml

Comment: 1. cp -r magento magento.before.install;  2. Run install; 3. diff -r magento magento.before.install

Comment: .. and then post your results as an answer. :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practice for conducting a Magento update?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757775/best-practice-for-conducting-a-magento-update)

Answer (score 0):

Just recently I checked out an unzip of magento 1.7 to local machine from svn and then installed magento (on local).. when I try to commit, it seems that none of the files got changed, there are only a few files in var folder added, such as log, cache etc .. and of course, local.xml