# Best practice for conducting a Magento update?

Tags: php, magento

What is the best practice for making a Magento update (of a badly maintained Magento installation).

I think of things like the following:

- Have a look at full overwrites modules in app/code/local - compare the files with the old version and forward-port them to the new Magento version
- Compare templates
- Compare layout XML files (if they were copied directly to the custom theme folder and no single layout.xml containing only the real updates was used)
- Compare the methods of the rewritten classes to the methods of the original class

The main problem is: When diffing files in old, badly maintained Magento installations, you never know, which version the original file that was copied had. Sometimes I tried to identify the old version by having a look on Magento's copyright in the file comment.

To avoid hassle during update we usually do the following:

- Avoid rewrites, use events instead
- If rewrites are necessary, try to not copy code but call parent::method() to keep only the necessary functionality in the overwritten class
- If copying code is necessary, use a marker-comment such as `[Mycompany BEGIN] ... [Mycompany END]`
- Do not copy entire layout files but use a single layout.xml that does only updates.

But how to do an update if those precautions where not taken?

Comment: This type of question doesn't really belong on Stack Overflow, as it's not a programming question. You should take a look at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25439/magento and see about getting a proper place to put these kind of questions

Comment: @paperids: Diffing around and porting code to a new version is also realated to programming. But thanks for the pointer to the stackexchange proposal.

Answer (score 11):

As others have noted the key here is to make it comparable against clean installation so here's what I would do with the help of version control.

1. get yourself the clean version of Magento you are currently on and don't forget to make it comparable. Or use a existing git mirror of magento (see more http://blog.speedupmate.com/post/4063307705/magento-git-mirror )
2. set up a master repo based on 1. here and have it at hand

   Asked in comments: Your ultimate goal is to have a clean core with all files in git that are present in magento installation files. That is needed so you can compare everything against the clean installation. Managing core changes, core filetree (existing, non-existing, added files). You can handle your exceptions with .gitignore (excluding media , cache,  all fiels with server specific scope local.xml .htaccess). I find it easy to move out Magento core files to different (non public) directory (as explained here http://blog.speedupmate.com/post/9992573819/poor-mans-multisite-setup-for-magento ) and that will give me a code state where .htaccess never conflicts on upgrade. I also never include media in version control , cache and all temporary files that magento generates. This will guarantee you clear path on upgrades as you can disable all for the upgrade time. Comparing the code later  will give you scope  of things you need to overview and you can estimate how long it will take you to compare the changed parts and go live with upgrade.
3. now with your existing site and git config in place (to make it comparable) do a `git init` on your codebase and add everything to git there , this will go over your git config and make every file comparable (same newlines, whitespaces etc) then fix file permissions to be the same. After that you can remove the .git folder from your site as you only used git to make files comparable there.

   Asked in comments: The point here is to have git do work for you like converting all line endings to unix style and ignore whitespaces, you can ignore permissions too in theory but that's not useful (formatting is bit off here so \ represents a line break between commands

   `git config core.autocrlf input \
    git config core.eol lf \
    git config apply.whitespace nowarn`

   Now if you do `git init`
   and add those configs and add everything to git then during committing stage git will replace all your windows line endings and all that crap to unified and comparable style. Note that zend coding standard suggest unix style line endings however you will also see the files where Zend library does not follow it's own standards. Key point here is that you need your files to be comparable to minimize the diff load you have to do. You will remove the  .git folder after git has formatted all your bad installation files for you. Git is only used to automate the "make things comparable process" in this step and nothing else
4. checkout your test repository based from your master repo in 1. and checkout a branch with the version you are currently on and name it "testsomething" or whatever you need
5. delete everything from that checkout folder and leave only .git in place so it is empty but version control still exists there. It will be in state like everything is deleted and this is important here cause based on that you will know what files you might have deleted on your bad site.

   Asked in comments: I usually add whitespace ignoring to git config (local or global scope is available)  and let git handle that for me. When working in teams we always agree on based Zend standards: 4 spaces for tabs, unix style line endings and git config variables mentioned at 3. and if build scripts are involved we do code formatting and validation with commit hooks.
6. move in all files to your empty dir (note that you have removed the .git dir from your existing site after making it comparable) from your f*cked up magento installation (they are comparable now) and run a `git status  > changes.txt` . This file now lists every difference you have , any new file you have, any deleted, renamed, etc file you have on your "f*cked up installation" against the clean Magento code that you are currently on.

   Explaining based on comments: I usually do `git status --porcelain`
7. have a .gitignore file in place to help you discard local.xml var/* or every file/dir that you don't need to version control and also .DS_Store, .Thumbs.db and your ide created project files from git. YOu don't need all Media and cached files and files that are different in each server on your version control.

From there you should overview that list carefully and based on that list you should:

- move every core change to app/code/local/ and checkout the changed file to it's original state (keep the copied one and discard the changes in core with `git checkout filename`)
- move every changed core template and layout file to your own theme folder  and checkout the changed file to it's original state
- revert or migrate .htaccess changes or decide if you need to preserve or discard

Now you still are in bad shape but you are now:

- based on clean core
- based on versioned master tree in a separate branch

Now you can benefit on being version controlled, comparable and in separate branch based on your master branch that has mergable versions of Magento in it. So lets try to upgrade, here's the key points of 100% success on doing this.

1. first step would be disable all the "crap" that you have now separated to app/code/local/Mage/ and to separate theme. If your core is clear and themes can be disabled you have no custom code interfering with upgrade process. So go ahead disable:

   - all local extensions and custom community extensions by moving them out of app/etc/modules/ to temp folder let it be app/etc/inactive/
   - disable custom themes and turn on base/default/
   - this is your benefit on being in comparable state. You know what's different and you can disable that and diagnose things based on that
2. now if you have all major versions in the master tree in your repo tagged or branched separately then getting the version higher is just a command away: git merge "magento-vhateverthenextversionis"

   - again after doing this "git status > changes.txt" will give you a list of all changed files between your versions
   - executing the site on browser will perform the upgrade and since you are on default theme and no customisations activated it will perform like a charm
   - repeat the upgrade version by version and save your code state by tagging in your test branch or create a new branch for each version based on existing testing branch , this way you have saved clean state for every magento version you have upgraded in between
   - again the extra bonus here is that if you do it with version control you also will get rid of the files that new versions discard and you can delete them easily
3. if you have iterated the 2. to your desired magento version to latest then it is time to eat the "s*it" that you have inherited and do following:

   - analyse all extensions you have and see if they can be upgraded, if you can upgrade and turn on see if they work with default theme
   - diff each core rewrite in app/code/local/Mage against it's original version in new form from app/code/core/Mage. You can use diff tools like winmerge.org or changes (whatever os and tool you prefer) one by one or diffing whole folders
   - same goes with your template and overwritten templates or layouts. COmpare to original and merge your changes to new base template and get rid from old DOM
   - turn on theme changes and extensions one by one and debug
4. if you get to this point then you have done a shitload of work , dependant how messed up the installation is it can take days. But hey now you have a clean magento core that is version controlled, separated overwrites that are merged and overviewed , and all stuff in separate theme that can be disabled.
5. fun part is that if next upgrade of magento is available you can whistle and add it as comparable to your master tree and merge down the changes, know what is changed and have a clear scope on what to overview and test.

Comment: A good and detailed answer. We do things similar.
Please could you elaborate on 3. in the first listing? To be honest I didn't understand what's the use of doing `git init` and then remove the .git folder again without changing anything in the repository.
Relating to 6.) In this situation you also may want to do something like `git diff -p --diff-filter=M -b -w > modifications.txt` on some or all files. You get to see which files have been changed in modified files, ignoring whitespaces which you can ignore at this point.

Comment: Relating to 2.) in your second listing: how do you handle unnecessary files that the merge whould re-introduce? (Unneeded template themes, skins etc.). The same goes for directories like media/ which we replaced with symlinks to easily switch between our shop code releases while using the same media folder. We have to take care that media/ stays a symlink and doesn't get replaced with a directory.

Comment: Edited my answer on 2, 3, 6 . I don't manage unneeded template themes that come with installation package I never remove or ignore them as i need the "state" to be comparable and they don't interfere with my doings anyway. My goal is to never change any file that comes with installation package and have all edits as extensions, separate locale files, separate theme/skin files. I ignore the media, tmp and all the files that Magento generates on the fly from version control. Git his here to manage changes in general for me, keeping it separated is just  the key to being in "comparable state"

Answer (score 1):

I'll begin by noting that your question's content indicates a clear understanding of (what I at least consider to be) best practices.

Regarding the potential multiple versions of origin: the goal of a software upgrade is to have the new classes and methods in place, period. That means (as you mentioned) porting *any* customizations regardless of how they were implemented.

Outside of diligent diff'ing, the best technique for your situation unfortunately will be **regression testing** - checking the generated output for multiple views.

It could very well be the case that you may need to punt, i.e. **start with a clean install and actively bring in the custom functionality & theming** which is still deemed necessary. This may not seem like the most efficient approach, but here are the benefits which I believe outstrip the apparent overhead:

1. You will be in control of all custom behavior with no surprises
2. You will be assured of a healthy codebase of single origin
3. **At some point to the client *you* become the owner of the code**, and a whitelist/affirmative approach to reintegrate customizations seems the best way to be sure that your ownership is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is to copy the site down to a development environment. Now make a backup of that, so that you can restore to that anytime you need to. Also at this point I would put the live site on code lockdown. No more changes to the code unless absolutely necessary (and if there are changes, you will have to duplicate them on the new development environment)

Now that you have a safe copy of the website available to you to play with, now the fun begins.

First thing I would do is pull down a copy of the stock version of Magento that you are running. Do a diff on /app/code/core between the stock version and what you currently have. This will tell you what your differences are. I would try to maintain all the functionality you currently have, while getting core back in order.

Hopefully at this point you have a pretty clean installation of Magento. You could consider pushing this back to the live server, but I have a feeling that you may have had to do a lot of monkeying around to get this far so it may not be a viable option.

Now I would make a separate backup of the development site so you can go back to this point if you need to.

Now, I would attempt the upgrade on the development site. Hopefully it all works out and you have no problems with the upgrade. If you do not, then make the corrections you need to and go on from there.

At this point you should have a code base that is stable with the upgrade. Backup live again (just to be safe), push the new code up, and hope that everything works out.

Comment: Thanks. But a "clean" Magento without any patches in app/code/core can still cause problems if a lot of classes were rewritten, layout files copied and so on. So there will be a lot of debugging later in a big Magento installation.